# String to [Char] in haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I got this string "bbbbffff", and I want to get a list in this form:

['b','b','b','b','f','f','f','f']

I think that I can use map, but sincerely, I don't know how to begin, and are a lot of things that I do not understand in Haskell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: those two are exactly the same thing in Haskell - the first is syntactic sugar for the second. So you don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I understand this, but, for example, the string has an undefined length, and I need to compare it with another list, so I need it explicitly in a list form. I don't know if I'm being clear.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not being clear to me. There is no such thing as "explicitly in a list form" - unless perhaps you are referring to a string representation? In Haskell a string simply *is* a list of characters, so you do not need to apply any "conversion function" to get from one to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a `String` is already a `[Char]` (see [specification](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1190006.1.2)):

> A string is a list of characters:
>
> ```
> type  String  =  [Char]
> ```

They simply don't print as `['b','b','b',...]` because `[Char]` and `String` is the same type and therefore indistinguishable and must be shown the same way. Indeed, if you input your list you'll see it formatted as a string:

```hs
Prelude> 42
42
Prelude> [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
Prelude> ['b','b','b','b','f','f','f','f']
"bbbbffff"
```

This means that you can immediately pass it to any list function, without having to do anything with it:

```hs
myLength :: [Char] -> Int
myLength (c:rest) = 1 + myLength rest
myLength [] = 0

-- Prints 11
main = print (myLength "hello world")
```

There are other textual data types like `Data.Text`, but these are for more advanced use and must be explicitly enabled and used.

Comment: i.e I need to do a ord 'a' + 1 this gave me 98, but I can not do the same with ord "a" + 1

Comment: This is because `'a'` is a `Char` and `"a"` is a `[Char]`. `ord` does not work on lists. If you want to do this to each character in the list, you can use `map`:  `map (\c -> ord c + 1) "foobar" == [103,112,112,99,98,115]`

Comment: @Raul I'm happy you got your answer before too long, but note that you only got it because you eventually you posed your *actual question* in a comment to this answer. Had you put the content of this comment as your actual question you'd probably have got the answer straight away - but the question you asked instead is not related to it so you instead got comments like mine which weren't helpful to you, because I couldn't guess the actual problem. Just something to think about the next time you need to ask something here.